# Linq, how to check if value of field is null

Tags: asp.net, linq, null, nullreferenceexception

while working with linq query i'm receiving error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

```
var db = from d in DepartmentBLL.GetDepartmentList()
     join b in BudgetMasterBLL.GetBudgetMasterList()            
     on d.Departmentid equals b.Departmentid into leftJoin                     
     from results in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new
     {
         Name = d.Name,
         Create = results.Budgetmasterid == null ? "null": "value", //ERROR HERE
         CreateURL = "frmBudgetInitial.aspx?departmentid=" + d.Departmentid.ToString() + "&departmentcategoryid=" + d.Departmentcategoryid.ToString()
     };
```

I found some help on forum but did not solve my problem, please advise. thanks.,

Comment: first check if results is null before using results.Budgetmasterid

Comment: Since results.Budgetmasterid is a string value, shouldn't you be checking for String.Empty instead of null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
Create = results == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(results.Budgetmasterid) ? "null": "value",
```

or

```
Create = results == null || string.IsNullOrWhitespace(results.Budgetmasterid) ? "null": "value",
```

Comment: This seems correct, but at the same time, this cannot solve first exception.

Comment: Agree. The dot (.) is still free to reference a null object.

Comment: @Ales I edited after your comments [at]Vladislav. is it right now?

Comment: Seems fine to me. But OP disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
Create = results == null || results.Budgetmasterid == null ? "null": "value", //ERROR HERE
```

Comment: Won't this assign `true` to `Create` if no results are returned?

Comment: Original condition is true when no result are returned. I just keep with that.

Comment: And by the way is it even possible for `results` to be null? I mean, empty collection != null?

Comment: results obviously is not collection (and has misleading name)

Comment: Oh, it should be `result` without the `s` :) Sorry, query syntax isn't that natural to me.